Trying to use NIntegrate and my code works intermittently - Throws one error consistently, but only gives me a partial result
I'm trying to do some calculations/simulations of pulse autocorrelations of non-integer orders and when I try to use NIntegrate it only works intermittently, and when it does work it only gives me a partial answer.
Here is the code:
Subscript[\[Tau], p]=50
Subscript[\[Tau], G]=Subscript[\[Tau], p]/1.177
E1 = A*Exp[-(1+I*a)(t/Subscript[\[Tau], G])^2]*Exp[-I*\[Omega]*t] /. A->1
E1C = A*Exp[-(1-I*a)(t/Subscript[\[Tau], G])^2]*Exp[I*\[Omega]*t] /. A->1
E2 = A*Exp[-(1+I*a)((t+\[Tau])/Subscript[\[Tau], G])^2]*Exp[-I*\[Omega]*(t+\[Tau])] /. A->1
E2C = A*Exp[-(1-I*a)((t+\[Tau])/Subscript[\[Tau], G])^2]*Exp[I*\[Omega]*(t+\[Tau])] /. A->1
z= E1 + E2 /.\[Omega] ->0/.a->0
I1 = ComplexExpand[Re[z^2], TargetFunctions -> Conjugate]
I2=(I1)^2
AC := NIntegrate[I2,{t,-100,100}]
maxVal = MaxValue[AC,\[Tau]] 
Show[Plot[Re[AC], {\[Tau], -100, 100},PlotRange->Full,GridLines -> {{-25, 25}, {maxVal, maxVal/2}},GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]]

Here are the "Total Failure" error messages:



Here are the "Partial Failure" error messages:

For the plot it is supposed to have gridlines in both x and y at the specified locations so I can measure the full-width at half-max of the output function. The only way I can get mathematica to output this partial failure version is to delete all output and then restart the kernel, but even this doesn't work consistently.
I'm very new to mathematica, so please avoid or explain mathematica-specific jargon if possible.

I can't see where $\tau$ has been defined a numerical value.

You can't use NIntegrate with non-numerical variables.
taup = 50;
tauG = taup/1.177;
E1 = A*Exp[-(1 + I*a) (t/tauG)^2]*Exp[-I*ω*t] /. A -> 1;
E1C = A*Exp[-(1 - I*a) (t/tauG)^2]*Exp[I*ω*t] /. A -> 1;
E2 = A*Exp[-(1 + I*a) ((t + τ)/tauG)^2]*Exp[-I*ω*(t + τ)] /. A -> 1;
E2C = A*Exp[-(1 - I*a) ((t + τ)/tauG)^2]*Exp[I*ω*(t + τ)] /. A -> 1;
z = E1 + E2 /. ω -> 0 /. a -> 0;
I1 = ComplexExpand[Re[z^2], TargetFunctions -> Conjugate];
I2 = (I1)^2;

int = Integrate[I2, {t, -100, 100}];
maxVal = MaxValue[int, τ]
 (* 602.363 *)

Show[Plot[Re[int], {τ, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  GridLines -> {{-25, 25}, {maxVal, maxVal/2}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]]



Right of course that makes sense. So, using NIntegrate, I'm assuming I would need to first specify a range for Tau and essentially make it an array of values?

@UltrashortGiraffe Yes, you could do nint = Table[NIntegrate[int, {t, -100, 100}], {\[Tau], -100, 100}]; ListPlot[nint]

@UltrashortGiraffe Or rather nint = Table[{\[Tau], NIntegrate[int, {t, -100, 100}]}, {\[Tau], -100, 100}]; to get {x,y} values.
